# Histoire Vite No support plugin found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I've been working on an npm repo; creating Vue-isolated components and publishing them as npm packages. Therefore there isn't a global App, so each package will have its own configuration (package.json, vite.config, etc). I was trying to create a Histoire folder where I can add my packages, but I'm getting errors all the time. I guess I'm not doing the proper config.?

I'm not sure how to make it work. I will appreciate some help here.

I made a reproduction of the error on Stack Blitz, you need to

> npm run story:dev

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9ebma3?file=histoire/histoire.config.js

Thanks!